# Textbox won't update to process output, but ShowMessage will (C#)

Tags: c#

Code excerpt:

```
ProcessStartInfo download = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
download.UseShellExecute = false;
download.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
download.CreateNoWindow = true;
var proc = Process.Start(download);
while (proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    outputBox.Clear();
    outputBox.Text = line;
}
```

If I have `MessageBox.Show(line)`; instead of `outputBox.Text = line`;, it works fine, and updates every time I press ok.
How would I have it update until the process finishes?

Comment: What is 'OutputBox'? Does it need a 'Refresh' or 'Invalidate' before rendering changes in its content?  Is this code executed in the UI-thread or in a separate Task (in that case, modifying controls created in the UI-thread will not work)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this command :

```
string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
outputBox.Clear();
outputBox.Text = line;
outputBox.Refresh();
Application.DoEvents();
```